Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist in TypeScript React
I'm trying to build a browser extension using React and TypeScript.
Context: I do npm run build and then copy my background.js & manifest.json file into the /build folder, this way I upload the /build folder to the browser. So far things work but when it comes to sending messages using both chrome.runtime.sendMessage() & chrome.tabs.sendMessage() I get the error Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist in TypeScript React.
I do have an eventListener for onMessage but I think it's not working...
I've checked most threads and forums but none seems to cover this issue properly.
Manifest.json - here I've used v3, and I use background.js as a file that sends the message.
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "name",
  "description": "description",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": ["tabs"],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },

  "action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html",
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "logo192.png",
      "32": "logo192.png",
      "48": "logo192.png",
      "128": "logo192.png"
    }
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "logo192.png",
    "32": "logo192.png",
    "48": "logo192.png",
    "128": "logo192.png"
  }
}

Background.js - logTabTitle function is sending the messages here.
function logTabTitle(tabId) {
  chrome.tabs.get(tabId, (tab) => {
    let title = tab.title;
    let url = tab.url;

    if (title !== "New Tab") {
      console.log(url);
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ type: "tabUpdate", title: title, url: url });
    } else {
      console.log(title);
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ type: "tabUpdate", title: title });
    }
  });
}

// Listen for tab activation
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener((activeInfo) => {
  logTabTitle(activeInfo.tabId);
});

// Listen for tab update (e.g., URL change)
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
  if (changeInfo.url) {
    logTabTitle(tabId);
  }
});

// Listen for window focus change
chrome.windows.onFocusChanged.addListener((windowId) => {
  if (windowId !== chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_NONE) {
    // Get the active tab in the focused window
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, (tabs) => {
      if (tabs && tabs.length > 0) {
        logTabTitle(tabs[0].id);
      }
    });
  }
});

My Tracker.tsx component - here I've placed eventListeners
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Tracker = () => {
  interface Tab {
    title: string;
    url: string;
  }
  const [activeTabs, setActiveTabs] = useState<Tab[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Inside the useEffect()");
    // Listener function for messages from background script
    const messageListener = (message: any) => {
      console.log("Message: ", message);
      if (message.type === "tabUpdate") {
        const { title, url } = message;
        setActiveTabs((prevTabs) => [...prevTabs, { title, url }]);
      }
    };

    // Cleanup function to remove the listener when component unmounts
    return () => {
      chrome.runtime.onMessage.removeListener(messageListener);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="">
        <div>Active Tabs</div>
        <ul>
          {activeTabs.map((tab: any, index: any) => (
            <li key={index}>
              {tab.title} - {tab.url}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Tracker;

Thanks.

chrome.runtime.sendMessage sends to the popup, but the popup runs only when it's shown. It means you don't need the background script and messages: simply move your entire code from background.js into the popup's code and instead of sendMessage directly call setActiveTabs.
